# Unknown array elemts appear?

Tags: php, arrays

I was writing one code, when suddenly I've found out, that some strange values appear.

```
    function purify($output){
    $temp = 0;
    $max_index = count($output);
    for($i=0;$i < $max_index; $i++){
        if(strlen($output[$i]) == 3){
                $str = str_split($output[$i]);
                arsort($str);
                $str = implode($str);
                $output[$temp] = $str;
                $temp++;
        }
        else unset($output[$i]);
    }
    return array_unique($output);
}
```

When I pass an array consisting from these elements:

```
11 115 165 138 999 885 999 456 135 726 642 425 426
```

I get this output:

```
array(11) { [1]=> string(3) "651" [2]=> string(3) "831" [3]=> string(3) "999" [4]=> string(3) "885" [6]=> string(3) "654" [7]=> string(3) "531" [8]=> string(3) "762" [9]=> string(3) "642" [10]=> string(3) "542" [12]=> string(3) "426" [0]=> string(3) "511" }
```

How did the 12th element ([12]=> string(3) "426") get there when `$temp` only went up to 11? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: What are your trying to do ?? oO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good practice to change the array `$output` as you are iterating through it.

Consider creating a new array called `$result` and change this line:

```
 $output[$temp] = $str;
```

to:

```
 $result[$temp] = $str;
```

This way you won't touch `$output` until the end of the loop.

It seems to me that you are seeing weird indexes because your changes of `$output` influence the next iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are overwriting the parameter *output* array, the elements initially in the array remain where they are (except if their length is != 3).

Maybe you could try

```
function purify($output){
    $result = array();
    $max_index = count($output);
    for($i=0;$i < $max_index; $i++){
        if(strlen($output[$i]) == 3){
                $str = str_split($output[$i]);
                arsort($str);
                $result[] = implode($str);
        }
    }
    return array_unique($result);
}
```

By the way, do you really want to use `arsort` and not `rsort`? `rsort` makes sense since you are using an indexed array (and not an associative array).

```
                rsort($str);
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, I get a bit lost with the sort functions a bit. So rsort for indexed and arsort for associative array? Thank you very much!

Comment: The result of `explode` is an indexed array `0 -> item1, 1 -> item2 etc...`, this is what you want for your `$str` array.